# Does community management belong on here?

Tags: discussion, suitable-question

Do you consider questions about community management of a website to be on-topic or off-topic?

Answer (score 8):

There are several community management questions already:

[How do you handle Suicide Threats?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-do-you-handle-suicide-threats)
[Where do you draw the line on hate speech in user generated content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1298/where-do-you-draw-the-line-on-hate-speech-in-user-generated-content)

Personally, I'm not interested in these questions, but I don't see them as off-topic since this is part of webmastering, isn't it?

Comment: +1, its a MAJOR part of running a site.

Comment: Depends on the site.

Answer (score 2):

Community management should be on-topic. For example, *[Is there any way to really ban people from a website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/720/is-there-any-way-to-really-ban-people-from-a-website/731)*  is a great question, and is a community manaegment question.

Obviously "on-topic" is on a case by case basis, but I think community management is on-topic.